# Getting javainstantiationexception in android

Tags: android

I am working on android applications. In my application I am using two **packages**. I have created a **login class** and **tabbarview** class in my first package. In the second package I have created three classes i.e **tab1,tab2,tab3**. 
      In my login class I wrote code for button click action i.e in the button click I called the TabbarView.class

```
         **Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),TabbarView.class);
              startActivity(myIntent);
              finish();**
```

I have imported the classes(tab1,tab2,tab3) of **second package** in my Tabbarview class. When I am executing my application I am getting exception.

**08-23 14:28:29.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pl.magot.vetch.ancal/pl.magot.vetch.ancal.TabbarView}: java.lang.InstantiationException: pl.magot.vetch.ancal.TabbarView**

When I click on login button I am getting this exception. What would be the reason. Please help me...............

Comment: Isn't there a nested exception or cause to this exception ?

Comment: no only this exception..when I am having 2 packages can you tell me how to place the two packages in manifest file

Comment: show your manifest, and give the Fully Qualified Names of your classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Login.this,TabbarView.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);
                  finish();
```

Comment: <activity android:name=".Welcome"></activity>
<activity android:name=".SMS"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Invoice"></activity>
  <activity android:name=".NewAppliance"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".Customerinfo"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".DisplayCustomers"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".activities.Tab"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".activities.TabHostProvider">/activity>
            <activity android:name=".activities.TabView"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".activities.TabbarView"></activity>